# How to read a file from a specific line to another specific line?

Tags: java, io

So I'm trying to make a file reader to read from x line to y line but when i execute the program it reads all the lines of the file and not the lines that should have started and ended, For example if i'm looking an ID in the file it should print de ID, The name of the holder(the next line of the ID Line), and his/her address(Next line of the name Line), but instead of print just that it prints all the ID'S, Names and Addresses of everyone in the file.

```
System.out.println("Escriba el ID Del Cliente");
         CL.setID(reader.next());
         String line2;
         int count = 0;
         try {
             BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
             Scanner input2 = new Scanner(file);
             PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true));
             LineNumberReader readers = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));

             while((line2 = input.readLine()) != null)
             {

                 if(line2.contains(CL.getID()))
                 {
                     while(((line2 = readers.readLine()) != null) && readers.getLineNumber() <= count + 3)
                     {
                         count++;
                         System.out.println(line2);


                     }

                     input.close();
                     input2.close();
                     output.close();
                     readers.close();
                     break;
                }





             }

         }catch(IOException ex)
         {
             System.out.println("ERRORR!!!!!!");
         }
```

Comment: It's because you're incrementing the `count` variable in every iteration. Just remove `count++` and it should work.

Comment: Hi, that fixed the bug of showing all the lines of the file, but now it just shows the first line of  the file and does not show the x line to y line i want the console to print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code because the problem was at the `count++` which will eventually led to reading all the lines from your files, and at the `line2 = readers.readLine()` which will read from the first line of the file again ( the program works **half** correct because it reads only 3 lines and only if line2 contains your ID ). Now, to make your program work correctly, you need to either use the `BufferedReader` or the `LineNumberReader`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Escriba el ID Del Cliente");
    String line2;
    File file = new File(yourpathhere);
    int lineCount = 0;
    try {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true));
        LineNumberReader readers = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
        while ((line2 = readers.readLine()) != null) {
            lineCount++;
            if (line2.contains(CL.getId())) {
                while (line2 != null && readers.getLineNumber() <= lineCount + 3) {
                    System.out.println(line2);
                    line2 = readers.readLine();
                }
                output.close();
                readers.close();
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERRORR!!!!!!");
    }
    }
```

**PS** : pay attention for the `getLineNumber()` method because it increments the lines read until the moment you're calling it. It means that if we didn't had the `lineCount` and the ID we're trying to find was at the 6th line, the `getLineNumber()` value at the moment when `line2.contains(CL.getId()) == true` was 6, so the `readers.getLineNumber() <= 3` will be **FALSE** and the program won't work correctly anymore. ( We need to keep track for the lines read until the moment we check for the id )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file with 100 lines and you want to check and print out line 5 to 10 you could try this:

```
System.out.println("Escriba el ID Del Cliente");
CL.setID(reader.next());
String line;
int count = 0;
int xLine = 5;
int yLine = 10;
try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)))
{
    while((line = input.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(count < xLine)
        {
            // skip all lines lower then start
            continue;
        }
        else if(count >= xLine && count <= yLine && line.contains(CL.getID()))
        {
            // print line if line is between lines to read
            // and if line contains ID
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        else
        {
            // break if count is bigger then yLine
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
}
catch(IOException ex)
{
    System.out.println("ERRORR!!!!!!");
}
```

You read all lines till the BufferedReader reaches `null`. You check if the line contains your ID. Then you check if the count is between the linenumbers you want to check / print. Then you increment the count for the lines processed.

I simplified the try-catch-Block with a [try-with-ressources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). As for now I don't see what your plans with `output` and `scanner` were, so I removed them.